# NodeJs: Unexpected token < error in javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a single and a very simplest form of webpages where, i have created a js file for Nodejs: which looks like this:-

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  
   fs.readFile('treeDemoinJavaScript.html', function (err, html) {
     if (err) {
        throw err; 
     }
    res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(html);
    res.end();
});
}).listen(8090);
```

Then comes the file treeDemoinJavaScript.html, which looks like this:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<br>
<h2>Linked List in Javascript</h2>

<p>Click the button to sort the array in ascending order.</p>
INPUT
<input type="text"  id="inputList"> </input>
<button onclick="insertInTree()">Add in Tree</button>
</br>
<button onclick="insertIntoTree()" id="show">Show in Tree</button></br></br>
<button onclick="search()" id="search">Search in Tree</button>
<input type="text" id="searchtextbox" visibility="hidden" placeholder="type the input "> </input>
<button onclick="deletefunction()" id="delete">Delete from Tree</button>
<p id="demo">welcome, the array is as follows: </p>
<p id="demo2">welcome, the array is as follows: </p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="treeDemoInJavaScript.js">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now what the problem is that even if i place a simple alert function in my treeDemoInJavaScript.js file that doesn't work and when i run
by doing
**$terminal- node startNodeDemo.js**
Then in the chrome i get the following error, like this:
[image]
Error shows :- **Unexpected token <**
and i don't get that why does browser running the treeDemoInJavaScript.js file and showing error in it.

Comment: your server seems to be sending the HTML file for every request, and has no way of returning the JS file.

Comment: before a proper answer can be provided, it's important to know:  Are you trying to do this without node plugins on purpose or would an example with plugins designed to deal with this situation be appropriate?  In other words, is there some reason you are using `fs`, and not something like express?

Comment: A node.js server serves up NO files by default.  So, your node.js server is configured to send `treeDemoinJavaScript.html` no matter what is requested of it.  So, the browser requests `treeDemoinJavaScript.html` and the server sends that.  Then the browser parses that HTML file and finds a reference to `treeDemoinJavaScript.js` so it request that from the web server, but your web server just sends it `treeDemoinJavaScript.html` which is why you get an error when the browser tries to run that as Javascript.  You need to support a route in your web server for `/treeDemoinJavaScript.js`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that, for each request, it reads `treeDemoinJavaScript.html`, adds a header value of `text/html`, and writes the contents of the HTML file to the response.

If your browser needs `treeDemoInJavaScript.js`, it will request it from server, but the server will send an HTML file instead. The browser doesn't understand it, and hence throws the error.

First of all, I will recommend to read [this post](https://blog.risingstack.com/your-first-node-js-http-server/). It will guide you on how to set a server up using NodeJS. The code you used defines the server interactions at very low-level. Using a dedicated framework for such cases, such as [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) is highly recommended.

Coming to the solution of your problem, [this simple gist](https://gist.github.com/mitrakmt/8227f72e4a6ff1381d9b37a966088087) will help you enable your code to serve JS files.

Comment: But all i am wanting to do is, to make a simple and the very minimal code, and that means not using the Express framework, so then how  can i make that happen by making small changes in this code only.

Comment: @SiddharthChoudhary -- _make a simple and the very minimal code_ -- That's what express does. Otherwise, you will have to have an if block checking the URL for JS files, and return the response accordingly. This is what is done in the gist.

Comment: so now as you suggested, i installed express in my app folder. Now what should i do with my startingfile ,i mean with the code which is located in index.js file, can you please let me know?? @31piy

Comment: @SiddharthChoudhary -- Did you go through the recommended post, which I mentioned in the answer? It contains an example of working with ExpressJS.

Comment: Well i got your point but now i am confused that will i need to make the following structure as mentioned in the blog or i can use directly the app.use or app.get() method and can redirect it to my html file. Well i assume later one, could be done @31piy

Comment: well I got your point, but if this is the case, then how is my code working when I don't use a separate file and instead of that, I included the file's javascript code inline @31piy

Comment: hey @31piy , i tried your approach by following the express and created the directory hierarchy as it was mentioned in the blog, but still i am unable to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

In your server side:

```
res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```

This is a typo mistake, instead of `res.writeHeader`, you should have used `res.writeHead`, as:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
```

**Second:**

You're responding all requests as the content of the file `treeDemoinJavaScript.html`. When the page loads, this line will make another request to server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="treeDemoInJavaScript.js">
```

Because of your mistake, it defaults response the file `treeDemoInJavaScript.js` with `treeDemoInJavaScript.html`'s content, start with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it's not valid syntax for javascript, so the error comes. To solve, refer @31piy's answer.

Comment: I don't think this is right.  If you look at the screenshot, the file being viewed is `treeDemoInJavaScript.js`, but the **contents of that file** are `treeDemoinJavaScript.html`.  This is clearly because the server is only doing one thing; retrieving the file `treeDemoinJavaScript.html` and sending it, **for every request**, no matter which file was requested.

Comment: @Claies Because `Content-Type` is not set properly, so the response is Javascript instead of HTML.

Comment: no, no, no.  Because **the browser requested a javascript file but the server is hard coded to send the HTML file for everything.**  If you actually look at the screenshot, it rendered the HTML just fine.

Comment: @Claies Oh, I see.

Comment: well I got your point, but if this is the case, then how is my code working when I don't use a separate file and instead of that, I included the file's javascript code inline

Comment: Then your code makes only 1 request, the server will response the content of `treeDemoinJavaScript.html` file, with javascript inside of it, then script gets executed normally.

Answer (score 1):

Well I solved my issue, after putting a wastage of a day.
I did it by two ways:

1. By using Express.js as was suggested by @31piy by [this blog](https://blog.risingstack.com/your-first-node-js-http-server/),
   starting with express.js, I created and installed Express.js 
   by *npm install express --save* command and had got a package.json file.
   Now the story starts with creating the directory structure as was taught.
   But here comes the mistake in this blog being done is, they have not guided you about the static files in express.js which was essential, because I added my javascript file everywhere but it was not reading it.

**So what I needed to do was create a public folder parallel to views folder and then place my javascript file in it.
And then using the line
*app.use(express.static('public'))*** 
to let Express know that some static files need to be include. And thus then directly using javascript.js in it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<br>
<h2>Linked List in Javascript</h2>

<p>Click the button to sort the array in ascending order.</p>
INPUT
<input type="text"  id="inputList"> </input>
<button onclick="insertInTree()">Add in Tree</button>
</br>
<button onclick="insertIntoTree()" id="show">Show in Tree</button></br></br>
<button onclick="search()" id="search">Search in Tree</button>
<input type="text" id="searchtextbox" visibility="hidden" placeholder="type the input "> </input>
<button onclick="deletefunction()" id="delete">Delete from Tree</button>
<p id="demo">welcome, the array is as follows: </p>
<p id="demo2">welcome, the array is as follows: </p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">
</script>
```

```
 and this is my index.js
```

```js
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')

const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))
//app.use("/styles", express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  extname: '.hbs',
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts')
}))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.render('home',{
    name: 'John'
  })
})
app.listen(8000)
```

2. And now the Second way which is without using any Express.js

   well what my code here troubling with is this is rendering the js file and sending the html file which browser doesnot understand, as been pointed by other commentators. **So what i did is used the switch case (as suggested by my friend) and changed the content-type of response
   which looks like this**

```js
var http = require("http"),
//url = require("url"),
path = require("path"),
fs = require("fs"),
mime = require("mime");


http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  console.log('request starting...');
  var filePath = '.' + request.url;
  if (filePath == './')
      filePath = './treeDemoinJavaScript.html';
      var extname = path.extname(filePath);
      var contentType = 'text/html';
      switch (extname) {
          case '.js':
              contentType = 'text/javascript';
              break;
          case '.css':
              contentType = 'text/css';
              break;
          case '.json':
              contentType = 'application/json';
              break;
          case '.png':
              contentType = 'image/png';
              break;
          case '.jpg':
              contentType = 'image/jpg';
              break;
          case '.wav':
              contentType = 'audio/wav';
              break;
      }

  fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
    if (error) {
      if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
          response.writeHead(500);
          response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
          response.end();
      }
      else {
          response.writeHead(500);
          response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
          response.end();
      }
  }
  else {
      response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
      response.end(content, 'utf-8');
  }
  
  });

}).listen(8090);
```

and hence it worked.
If it doesn't works in your case,then do focus on the paths which you might have given wrong or try to create new directory and do it neatly by including minimal files which you require